# Chef DataBag new databag values are not being used on chef run but using the old databag

Tags: chef-infra

I have created a new databag with same values but some passwords are changed in the new databag using the same encryption key.In the chef code I have changed the default databag to the new databag from old one but chef is stilling using the old databag values.Can someone please assit me on this.

Answer (score 0):

this could mean a lot of things, to make sure that the changes have been made to you chef server you you should try to use knife to show it

```
knife data bag show DATA_BAG_NAME (options)
```

reference here: https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_data_bag/

if the databag there is updated you should check if your machine is able to get the databag.

Comment: I have checked show command to make sure values are correct in databag locally in my machine and  Chef is running on EC2 instances.